# Angulart test - SassError

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I've problem with testing in Angular 13.
I've been creating my variables, and after that, when i running tests i've problem like that:

```
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.


25 │ @import "variables";
   │         ^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵

  src/styles.scss 25:9  root stylesheet

./src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
```

I have no idea how to fix that. I've been trying import node modules to tsconfig.spec.json
include path for node_modules, but i'm faild.

Project has no problem with running or buildng from CLI but test are crushed.
Have You any ideas?

Comment: This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48844134/14645652) might work for this

Comment: Nope it's not working